# How do I insert the null value in a Boolean attribute when using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, null, nullable

I have a class with a Boolean attribute. When I instantiate and persist this class, the Boolean attribute is stored with the "false" value instead of the expectable "null". How can I  set a Boolean attribute to "Null"?

Comment: Morte Rolo Can you show your class and its mapping ???

Comment: @Arthur Ronald F D Garcia: It is just a regular @Entity class with a @Column Boolean attribute.

Comment: Your database must be doing this. What database and what column type are you using?

Comment: SQLServer tinyint default null

Comment: You may have run into this bug http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3716 
The report mentions Sybase, but SQLServer is a close relative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird problem. A `Boolean` attribute with a `null` value is definitely supposed to be stored as `NULL` and the `tinyint` column type allows that. I cannot investigate the problem myself but here is what I would do:

First, I would activate the logging of Hibernate's DML statements and of JBDC parameters to confirm that Hibernate is actually passing `NULL` (and it should). The relevant categories (chapter [3.5. Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)) are `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type`.

If the first test doesn't reveal the problem, I would try to isolate it further with a simple test class using raw JDBC to insert a `Boolean` with a `null` value (and also read it). If this test is not positive, then I would start to suspect the JDBC driver.

What JDBC driver (and version) are you using by the way? If you are using the Microsoft driver, try with the latest version of [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) (and inversely).

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure that you define a `Boolean` object and not a `boolean` type.

Then, if you are using Hibernate with JPA attributes, then you can add `@Column(nullable=true)` to explicitly tell Hibernate the the column should have NULL as default.

Comment: nullable attribute is, by default, true

Comment: What is the schema of your table? Does it allow for NULL values in that column?

Furthermore, you can try debugging the code where you create a new instance. Maybe the value is initialized to false in your code.

Comment: The value is explicitly initialized to "null", the "schema" represents this attribute as a tinyint with null as default value

Comment: Have you tried putting your Boolean value as null as default?
`Boolean value = null;`

Answer (score 2):

First you make sure that the object you are trying to persist is Boolean not primitive boolean. Secondly, you can define the column corresponding as char(1) which can hold 'Y', 'N' or null value. and lastly,and the most important add the following line to you hibernate.cfg.xml :-

```
<property name="query.substitutions">'Y'=true,'N'=false</property>
```

if u are using hibernate.properties file then use following:-

```
hibernate.query.substitutions true 'Y', false 'N'
```

this would help you out to store null values to boolean type column. and don't forget to map the property as type="boolean" in the mapping file.