# Empty value for boolean

Tags: oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot 3 application, I use an Oracle database.

I have a field of type

```
char(1).
```

In db there is 0, 1 and no value.

In java

```
@Column(name = "privatePhone", columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
private boolean privatePhone = false;
```

I got an sql exception

at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBoolean(CharCommonAccessor.java:207) ~[ojdbc11-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]

When i check

```
CharCommonAccessor
```

class of Oracle driver

```
boolean getBoolean(int var1) throws SQLException {
    String var2 = this.getString(var1);
    if (var2 != null && !var2.trim().equals("0") && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("f") != 0 && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("false") != 0 && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("n") != 0 && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("no") != 0) {
        if (!var2.trim().equals("1") && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("t") != 0 && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("true") != 0 && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("y") != 0 && var2.trim().compareToIgnoreCase("yes") != 0) {
            throw (SQLException)DatabaseError.createSqlException(this.getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 59).fillInStackTrace();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

var2 value is empty

how to manage that

Comment: there is no boolean data type in Oracle SQL.

Comment: can you change the table definition? If yes just add the default value for that column "0"

Comment: In Oracle empty string is the same as `null`. You need to adjust your data to store `t/f` or `y/n` or use different java class. This question seems to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13013227/2778710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception you are facing tells that the empty value stored in your `char(1)` column does not equal either `0`/`f`/`false`/`n`/`no`, or `1`/`t`/`true`/`y`/`yes`.

As soon as on Java side you have primitive `boolean` field you should adjust your Oracle schema to enable only `1`/`0` (or `t`/`f` etc.) values, e.g.

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD private_phone char(1) DEFAULT '0' CONSTRAINT private_phone_constraint CHECK (private_phone IN ('0', '1'));
```

Alternatively, if you deal with legacy schema and empty values are already there then you need to implement custom field/column converter, e.g.:

```java
@Converter
public class BooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
        if (value == null {
            return "";
        }
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(value) ? "1" : "0";
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return "1".equals(value);
    }
}
```

Then in your entity you should refactor the field as

```java
@Convert(converter = BooleanConverter.class)
private Boolean privatePhone = false;
```

P.S. See [How do I insert the null value in a Boolean attribute when using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951009/how-do-i-insert-the-null-value-in-a-boolean-attribute-when-using-hibernate)